# Error accessing host port from docker container on ubuntu

Tags: docker

I'm trying to access a host port from a docker container running an OCaml stack. When I use the `--net=host` option when running the container I get the following error

```
Fatal error: exception # opam-version    1.2.2 (58ef3b8213100953848d362f7120a30356d7f77d)
# os              linux
opam: "execvp" failed on --net=host: No such file or directory
```

The contents of my `/etc/hosts` file are as follows

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Could someone please explain why I could be getting this error?

**EDIT**

The docker command I'm using is `docker run -it <repo-name> --net=host`

Comment: please post your complete docker command

Comment: Updated the question with the docker command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker parameters need to be listed before the container name. Otherwise they are interpreted as arguments of the container entrypoint. This should work:

```
docker run -it --network=host <repo-name>
```